# Artemis ActiveMQ - AMQ159005: Invalid Session Mode CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to create a session with Acknowledge mode CLIENT and facing the following exception:

```
JMSException: Could not create a session: AMQ159005: Invalid Session Mode CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE
```

Code:

```
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("java:/RemoteJmsDispatcher");

private Connection conn;
conn = factory.createConnection();

private Session session;
session = conn.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

RemoteJmsDispatcher:

```
 <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra-remote-dispatcher" entries="java:/RemoteJmsDispatcher java:jboss/exported/jms/ConnectionFactory" connectors="netty-remote-dispatcher" min-large-message-size="524288" client-id="wildfly-dev" retry-interval="5000" max-retry-interval="5000" group-id="my-broadcast-group" user="xxxxx" password="xxxxx" enlistment-trace="true">
     <inbound-config use-jndi="true" rebalance-connections="true" use-local-tx="false"/>
 </pooled-connection-factory>
```

I google the error code AMQ159005 and didn't find anything.

I need to create with this mode because I have a larger processing of messages and if I got some exception I need that the messages back to the Queue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what context are you trying to create this session?  Are you in an Java EE application server?  Are you creating the session from a connection created from a JCA-based connection factory?

Comment: Hi Justin, thanks for your reply. Yes, I'm using JBoss Wildfly 13.
I'm using a Remote ConncetionFactory to create my Connection.
 I added the code to the question.

Comment: Are you in an EJB? How is "java:/RemoteJmsDispatcher" defined in the server config?

Comment: Added to the question. About EJB I'm not sure. How can I confirm this? Thanks.

Comment: The class (or one of the callers up the chain) would likely either be annotated with @Stateless or be packaged in the deployment with an ejb-jar.xml file.

Comment: So no. I'm not in an EJB. I don't if this matters but I'm calling this method from an Apache Camel Route using .bean(). .bean(GetMessagesService.class, "getMessages(${header.messageQuantity})").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `pooled-connection-factory` is a JCA-based connection factory (from the Artemis JCA resource adapter) which doesn't allow `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` mode to be set on the session. See [here](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/1.x/artemis-ra/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/ra/ActiveMQRASessionFactoryImpl.java#L831).  I recommend you use a normal (i.e. non JCA-based) connection factory.

Comment: Ok. Got it. I'll check if is possible to create a non pooled-connection-factory on wildfly and used it. I understood the problem. Thanks for your help!